# Having problem in formatting an integer output

Tags: python

I am making a marksheet with design and everything and i have done everything i have used formatting on strings and it all work great but i am encountering a problem in 3 places,below is my code and after the code i will also give result so you can see where i am having problem.The problems comes on Marks and Grand Total.

```
        from datetime import datetime
        year=datetime.now().year
        date=datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
        while True:
                    while True:
                                Name=input("\nType your name:")
                                if len(Name)==0:
                                    print('''"You made mistake while filling name section"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    while True:
                                F_Name=input("\nType father name:")
                                if len(F_Name)==0:
                                    print('''"You made mistake while filling f.name section"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    while True:
                                School=input("\nType your school name:")
                                if len(School)==0:
                                    print('''"You made mistake while filling school section"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    while True:
                                Group=input("\nType your group eg.Science,Arts:")
                                if len(Group)==0:
                                    print('''"You made mistake while filling group section"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    while True:
                                Board=input("\nType name of your board:")
                                if len(Board)==0:
                                    print('''"You made mistake while filling board section"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    while True:
                                try:
                                    num1 = int(input('\nEnter number of total subjects:'))
                                except ValueError:
                                    print('''\n"Please enter only number"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    l_Subjects=[]
                    l_T_Marks=[]
                    l_Marks=[]
                    S_numbers=["first","second","third","fourth","fifth","sixth","seventh","eighth","ninth","tenth","eleventh","twelth","thirteenth","fourteenth","fifteenth","sixteenth","eighteenth","nineteenth","twentieth"]
                    for i in range(num1):
                            print(f'''\n"For the {S_numbers.pop(0)} subject"\n''')
                            Subjects=input("Type subject name:")
                            l_Subjects.append(Subjects)
                            while True:
                                try:
                                    T_Marks= int(input(f'Enter total marks for {Subjects}:'))
                                    l_T_Marks.append(T_Marks)
                                    while True:
                                        try:
                                            Marks = int(input('Enter obtained marks:'))

                                        except ValueError:
                                            print('''\n"Please enter only number"''')
                                        if Marks>T_Marks:
                                            print('''\n"Please insert correct marks"''')
                                        else:
                                                l_Marks.append(Marks)
                                                break
                                except ValueError:
                                    print('''\n"Please enter only number"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    print('''\n\n                              "Here is your Marksheet"\n\n''')
                    print("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"§                         {Board.title(): <54}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§") 
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")           
                    print(f"§    Examination      Annual {year: <51}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"§    Name             {Name.title(): <58}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"§    F.Name           {F_Name.title(): <58}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"§    School/Private   {School.title(): <58}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"§    Group            {Group.title(): <58}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print("§   _________________________________________________________________________   §")
                    print("§  |                                                                         |  §")
                    print("§  |                               Subjects                                  |  §")
                    print("§  |_________________________________________________________________________|  §")
                    print("§  |            Component             |                 Marks                |  §")
                    print("§  |__________________________________|______________________________________|  §")
                    l_T_Marks1=list(l_T_Marks)
                    l_Marks1=l_Marks.copy()
                    l_Subjects1=l_Subjects.copy()
                    for i in list(l_Marks):
                        print(f"§  |            {l_Subjects.pop(0): <22}|                 {l_Marks.pop(0)}/{l_T_Marks.pop(0): <17}|  §")
                        print(f"§  |__________________________________|______________________________________|  §")
                    Sum_Marks=(sum(l_Marks1))
                    Sum_T_Marks=(sum(l_T_Marks1))
                    Percentage=(Sum_Marks/Sum_T_Marks)*100
                    if(Percentage>=80):
                        Grade='A+'
                    elif(Percentage>=70 and Percentage<80):
                        Grade='A'
                    elif(Percentage>=60 and Percentage<70):
                        Grade='B'
                    elif(Percentage>=50 and Percentage<60):
                        Grade='C'
                    elif(Percentage>=40 and Percentage<50):
                        Grade='D'
                    else:
                        Failed=('''"Sorry! You have failed the exam."                  §''')
                        Grade='F'
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"§                                Grand Total {Sum_Marks} out of {Sum_T_Marks:<25}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print("§                                         _______                               §")
                    print("§                                        |       |                              §")
                    print(f"§                                Grade   |   {Grade.title(): <4}|                              §")
                    print("§                                        |_______|                              §")
                    if Grade=='F':
                        print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                        print(f"§                           {Failed: <5}")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print("§                                       Waseem Munir                            §")
                    print("§                                _________________________                      §")
                    print("§                                Controller of Examination                      §")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"§ Dated:{date: <72}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
                    while True:
                                Repeat=input("\nDo you want to repeat?\n\nYes or No:")
                                Repeat=Repeat.lower()
                                if Repeat not in ["yes","y","no","n"]:
                                    print('''"\nPlease select correct option"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    if Repeat in ["yes","y"]:
                        continue
                    else:
                        if Repeat in ["no","n"]:
                            print("\n-----Thank you for using-----")
                            input()
                            break
```

## This is the output.

```
                                    "Here is your Marksheet"


        <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        §                                                                               §
        §                                                                               §
        §                         Bermingham Board                                      §
        §                                                                               §
        §                                                                               §
        §    Examination      Annual 2019                                               §
        §                                                                               §
        §    Name             John Michael                                              §
        §                                                                               §
        §    F.Name           Brad Michael                                              §
        §                                                                               §
        §    School/Private   Bermingham High School                                    §
        §                                                                               §
        §    Group            Science                                                   §
        §                                                                               §
        §   _________________________________________________________________________   §
        §  |                                                                         |  §
        §  |                               Subjects                                  |  §
        §  |_________________________________________________________________________|  §
        §  |            Component             |                 Marks                |  §
        §  |__________________________________|______________________________________|  §
        §  |            Maths                 |                 76/100              |  §
        §  |__________________________________|______________________________________|  §
        §  |            English               |                 81/100              |  §
        §  |__________________________________|______________________________________|  §
        §                                                                               §
        §                                                                               §
        §                                Grand Total 157 out of 200                      §
        §                                                                               §
        §                                         _______                               §
        §                                        |       |                              §
        §                                Grade   |   A   |                              §
        §                                        |_______|                              §
        §                                                                               §
        §                                       Waseem Munir                            §
        §                                _________________________                      §
        §                                Controller of Examination                      §
        §                                                                               §
        § Dated:04-07-2019                                                              §
        §                                                                               §
        §                                                                               §
        <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

        Do you want to repeat?

        Yes or No:
```

Comment: you should use `{Sum_Marks: >3}` to always use 3 chars for numbers 0...200 or you should first create string `Grand Total 157 out of 200` and later put it in `§ {: <80} §` using format `<value`

Comment: in `76/100` you should also use `{: >3}/100` to use 3 chars for `76` with spaces at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use chars in all 3 places you are having problem in integers output you need to  change Grand Total {Sum_Marks:>3 or 4 #(as you need per output)} out of {Sum_T_Marks:<25}§").I have corrected the code down below.

```
        from datetime import datetime
        year=datetime.now().year
        date=datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
        while True:
                    while True:
                                Name=input("\nType your name:")
                                if len(Name)==0:
                                    print('''"You made mistake while filling name section"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    while True:
                                F_Name=input("\nType father name:")
                                if len(F_Name)==0:
                                    print('''"You made mistake while filling f.name section"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    while True:
                                School=input("\nType your school name:")
                                if len(School)==0:
                                    print('''"You made mistake while filling school section"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    while True:
                                Group=input("\nType your group eg.Science,Arts:")
                                if len(Group)==0:
                                    print('''"You made mistake while filling group section"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    while True:
                                Board=input("\nType name of your board:")
                                if len(Board)==0:
                                    print('''"You made mistake while filling board section"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    while True:
                                try:
                                    num1 = int(input('\nEnter number of total subjects:'))
                                except ValueError:
                                    print('''\n"Please enter only number"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    l_Subjects=[]
                    l_T_Marks=[]
                    l_Marks=[]
                    S_numbers=["first","second","third","fourth","fifth","sixth","seventh","eighth","ninth","tenth","eleventh","twelth","thirteenth","fourteenth","fifteenth","sixteenth","eighteenth","nineteenth","twentieth"]
                    for i in range(num1):
                            print(f'''\n"For the {S_numbers.pop(0)} subject"\n''')
                            Subjects=input("Type subject name:")
                            l_Subjects.append(Subjects)
                            while True:
                                try:
                                    T_Marks= int(input(f'Enter total marks for {Subjects}:'))
                                    l_T_Marks.append(T_Marks)
                                    while True:
                                        try:
                                            Marks = int(input('Enter obtained marks:'))

                                        except ValueError:
                                            print('''\n"Please enter only number"''')
                                        if Marks>T_Marks:
                                            print('''\n"Please insert correct marks"''')
                                        else:
                                                l_Marks.append(Marks)
                                                break
                                except ValueError:
                                    print('''\n"Please enter only number"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    print('''\n\n                              "Here is your Marksheet"\n\n''')
                    print("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"§                         {Board.title(): <54}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§") 
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")           
                    print(f"§    Examination      Annual {year: <51}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"§    Name             {Name.title(): <58}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"§    F.Name           {F_Name.title(): <58}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"§    School/Private   {School.title(): <58}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"§    Group            {Group.title(): <58}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print("§   _________________________________________________________________________   §")
                    print("§  |                                                                         |  §")
                    print("§  |                               Subjects                                  |  §")
                    print("§  |_________________________________________________________________________|  §")
                    print("§  |            Component             |                 Marks                |  §")
                    print("§  |__________________________________|______________________________________|  §")
                    l_T_Marks1=list(l_T_Marks)
                    l_Marks1=l_Marks.copy()
                    l_Subjects1=l_Subjects.copy()
                    for i in list(l_Marks):
                        print(f"§  |            {l_Subjects.pop(0): <22}|                 {l_Marks.pop(0):>4}/{l_T_Marks.pop(0): <16}|  §")
                        print(f"§  |__________________________________|______________________________________|  §")
                    Sum_Marks=(sum(l_Marks1))
                    Sum_T_Marks=(sum(l_T_Marks1))
                    Percentage=(Sum_Marks/Sum_T_Marks)*100
                    if(Percentage>=80):
                        Grade='A+'
                    elif(Percentage>=70 and Percentage<80):
                        Grade='A'
                    elif(Percentage>=60 and Percentage<70):
                        Grade='B'
                    elif(Percentage>=50 and Percentage<60):
                        Grade='C'
                    elif(Percentage>=40 and Percentage<50):
                        Grade='D'
                    else:
                        Failed=('''"Sorry! You have failed the exam."                  §''')
                        Grade='F'
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"§                                Grand Total {Sum_Marks:>4} out of {Sum_T_Marks:<23}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print("§                                         _______                               §")
                    print("§                                        |       |                              §")
                    print(f"§                                Grade   |   {Grade.title(): <4}|                              §")
                    print("§                                        |_______|                              §")
                    if Grade=='F':
                        print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                        print(f"§                           {Failed: <5}")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print("§                                       Waseem Munir                            §")
                    print("§                                _________________________                      §")
                    print("§                                Controller of Examination                      §")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"§ Dated:{date: <72}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print(f"{'§': <80}§")
                    print("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
                    while True:
                                Repeat=input("\nDo you want to repeat?\n\nYes or No:")
                                Repeat=Repeat.lower()
                                if Repeat not in ["yes","y","no","n"]:
                                    print('''"\nPlease select correct option"''')
                                else:
                                    break
                    if Repeat in ["yes","y"]:
                        continue
                    else:
                        if Repeat in ["no","n"]:
                            print("\n-----Thank you for using-----")
                            input()
                            break
```